# Is it important to declare the namespace with QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE .. QT_END_NAMESPACE

Tags: qt, qt4

What is the effect of QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE?

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QLineEdit;
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

If I don't use the class declaration like that, will any problem occur?

Comment: Check out this http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15946-What-s-effect-of-QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE-Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_In_Namespace

Answer (score 23):

`QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` and `QT_END_NAMESPACE` are preprocessor macros and they are defined in *QtGlobal* as:

```
#define QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE namespace QT_NAMESPACE {
#define QT_END_NAMESPACE }
```

But: those two macros only have any effect when Qt was configured and built using the `-qtnamespace` option, which allows you to build Qt inside a user-defined namespace.

So: if you don't use (or plan on using) a Qt library which was built this way (per default, the Qt library resides in the global namespace), omitting the `QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` and `QT_END_NAMESPACE` won't lead to any problems.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not use them, it may crash in certain scenarios.

> The Qt-in-Namespace feature serves as a tool to handle certain
> scenarios involving multiple configurations of Qt more gracefully.
> E.g. before Qt-in-Namespace a Qt 3 based application in Linux would
> immediately segfault as soon as it tries to dlopen() a shared object
> that is linked to Qt 4. With the Qt in namespace feature not only can
> the crash be prevented, but under certain circumstances this
> combination might actually "work".
> [source](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_In_Namespace)